# Writting bytes from openxmlformats-officedocument to a docx in Java

Tags: java, file, docx, fileoutputstream

I've a webservice which gets requests to save a docx file into an internal folder.
The request already contains byte array of the file that I should save, however, I am struggling to make it works.

**Problem:**
When I save the file into the folder and try to open the docx, it does not open, and Word says that it cannot be opened due to invalid file.

So, I've read some posts saying that Word documents are sort of zipped, if so, how could I write those bytes in order to generate the docx file correctly?

The type of the file in the request is:

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Below is the code. I suppose it cannot use FileOutputStream?

```
private void createAOLocalFile(byte[] document, String fileName) throws AOException {
    LOGGER.info("ENTER - createAOLocalFile(fileName: " + fileName + ")");

    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream= new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));) {
        fileOutputStream.write(document);
        LOGGER.info("EXIT - createAOLocalFile");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format(exceptionMessage, "createAOLocalFile"), ex);
        throw new AOException(ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you unzip the file using any zip tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong using `FileOutputStream` maybe your received data is corrupted. try to open the byte array using Apache POI.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.7-beta3</version>
    </dependency>

    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

[...]

    byte[] document; 
    XWPFDocument xWPFDocument = new XWPFDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(document));
```

if this statement throws exception then you are receiving byte array of corrupted document then there is something wrong with web service.

Comment: Thanks Veli! It's working fine after I started using POI. Very valuable.

Comment: Besides the valuable answer above, I had to set up the type of file which was being uploaded through the FTP API. It has ASCII by default, and it can be easily changed by using the method ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE). It's useful when handling with docx and xlms documents.